# Join Multiple Tables to a Spatial Map without using Database

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, spatial-join

I work with Spatial dataset in QGIS and as usual, it is linked to an attribute table.

What is now unusual to me is that the attributes data is now growing and my client doesn't want the data merged on one table. He needs different tables as the data comes in.

So, I want to know how I can have the spatial data linked to multiple tables without necessarily using a database engine. Just the normal attributes tables in QGIS linked to one spatial dataset?

I need a way to do this without using database (such SQLite, PostGIS, MySQL Spatial etc)?

If QGIS don't support this by default, any suggestion on any Open Source GIS plugin/software is also well come, but **no database**.

How do I link more than one Attribute tables to Spatial data on my map in QGIS (no database)?

Comment: Where is your spatial data stored?

Comment: Shapefiles on local widows PC

Comment: Did you trie to join those tables through layer properties >> join?  You can join more than 1 table

Comment: join is making the table grow bigger out of hand. That is why I look for a way to keep separate tables related to each other but not on a database.

Comment: Are you asking what format you can use to store your non-spatial data? If yes, you can use DBF, or even CSV (text with comma separated values) but you lose editing capabilities in QGIS in that case. I'm also wondering about the reason behind the desire to split the data in multiple tables. Is it to normalize the data (1-Many relationships) or is there some other reason?

Comment: As @PieterB suggested, you could do a **join** but you can also specify which fields you want joined. So the table does not need to get out of hand as you can choose to join one field from each table etc.

Comment: Am beginning to think of reconvincing my client to reconsider a database (SpatiaLite) for this.

Comment: What is at stake is that different potions of the  shapefile (map and table) is often sent to different rent departments for further processing. What is obtainable now is we query and extract relevant tables for each department, but actually there isn't need for the query if the tables are kept separately.  We could just forward the relevant table with the spatial data accordingly. So Join is not the way for us as the table become unacceptably bulky.

Comment: @Umar: the join is dynamical. So you can send the table to one department to update information, past it back in the location and the newly added info will show up in QGIS.  I'll post an answer so I can make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand well,you have one layer with spatial data and multiple tables.  In my example I have one pointlayer and two tables (depA and depB).

[image]

Both tables are linked to the point layer

[image]

If you change/add data in the linked tables (depA or depB), the changes will be shown in QGIS.

You can send table depA to one department.  When you get it back, replace the old table with the new table.

Warning: give it the same name and the referencing field (join field) has to be the same (see picture under).

[image]

Comment: This approach merges the contents of tables (depA and depB) into the pointlayer table. Is it not possible to open one of the tables (depA and depB) and interact with the pointlayer map directly?